# Why is the set $\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb C^3:z_1^2 +z_2^2+z_3^2=1 \}$ not compact?

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness

> Why  is the set $\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb C^3:z_1^2 +z_2^2+z_3^2=1 \}$ not compact in the Euclidean topology?

If we consider $\mathbb C^3$ as $\mathbb R^6$ and $z_n=x_n+iy_n \text{(n=1,2,3)}$ then I think the set will become closed and it is already bounded . Although why it is not compact?

Please someone help..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bounded. Set
$$
z_1=n(1+i), z_2=n(1-i), z_3=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your set is not bounded. For instance, it contains all the points of the form $$\bigl(it,\sqrt{1+t^2},0\bigr),$$with $t\in\mathbb R$.